# Mutt messages are not expunged after sync

Tags: arch-linux, mutt

When switching folder or exiting (with 'q') or manually syncing (with '$'), messages marked as `D` are not expunged.

So let's say I have 9 messages flagged `D`. When I quit, mutt says `[...], 9 deleted.`. When I open mutt again, the messages are still there, flagged `D`. When I quit again, mutt says `[...], 9 deleted.`.

Is it normal?

I'm using the Arch Linux' mutt package with Maildir mailboxes.

Here is my mailbox setup:

```
set folder = ~/mail/work/
set spoolfile = +inbox
set record = +outbox
set postponed = +drafts
set mbox = +mailbox
set maildir_trash = yes
set mbox_type = Maildir

mailboxes +inbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `~/.muttrc` folder, maybe there is setting

```
set delete = no
```

or could be specific for maildir format

```
set maildir_trash = yes
```

these settings prevent expunging.

If you want to expunge deleted messages on sync or quiting mutt use

```
set delete = yes
```

(or `ask-yes`, then `mutt` will ask you if you really want to remove selected messages) and

```
set maildir_trash = no
```

(or `set nomaildir_trash`).

Comment: Ok my bad, I thought `maildir_trash`'s purpose was to move deleted mails in a given trash folder.

Comment: in `neomutt` there is such option `trash`

Comment: @mrajner ...and in mutt 1.7

Comment: @mrajner How does that work?

Comment: @Antoine just put 
`set trash = '=mytrashfolder_where_i_want_move_deleted_messages'`
you can omit equal sign a specify absolute path for your trash folder or prepend like in example so trash folder will be relative to your folder variable -- see: `man muttrc` for details